# "Page not found" when clicking on inbox item

Tags: support, inbox

Since yesterday there is an entry in my "StackExchange" inbox, 
coming from a thread about "why is atomic density not linear..." .

The first line reads :

@Georg Given that this answer is in agreement with

When I click on this entry, I get "Page not found". 
But the thread does exist, although not this comment.

Strange

Georg

Comment: Odd, perhaps the comment was deleted. But the SE team will have to explain this one, I'm not sure exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is sometimes possible due to race conditions when someone adds a comment and then deletes it.